# Is there a way to open a file from a non-activity class in Kotlin on Android?

Tags: android, file, class, kotlin

I have a non-activity Kotlin class in my app. Since it doesn't have any visual stimulus for the user, I did not make it into an activity.

The class pulls a list from a file, which I put in the `res/raw` folder. According to the Android docs, I use `openRawResource()`, which requires a Context.

Other similar questions in Java show a variable being declared as a variable, but when I do this in Kotlin, it tells me that the `variable _context must be initialized`. This is my code so far:

```
val _context:Context = object: Context()
val _ignorereader = _context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ignorelist).bufferedReader()
val _ignorelist = _ignorereader.readLines().toTypedArray().toList()
return _ignorelist
```

Right now I'm getting the error: `Expecting a class body` from the first line.

Is there a way to open files in non-activity classes?

Comment: You can't create an instance of `Context` (i mean you should not, as it won't be working). Pass the context into your class from Activity, or other context-based class

Comment: I'm noticing that. Is there a way to open a file in this case?

Comment: yes, but as I said, you need to pass a valid `Context` into your class

Answer (score 1):

you need context for accessing resource. you can declare application context in Application class.

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this
    }
    companion object {
        var context: Context? = null
            internal set
    }
}
```

use this context anywhere in app like this.

```
fun test() {
        val _ignorereader = App.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test).bufferedReader()
        val _ignorelist = _ignorereader.readLines().toTypedArray().toList()
        return _ignorelist
    }
```

also make sure you have declare App in your manifest.

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
......>
</application>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's reverted to a previous bug where it's not able to find the the object that I created in that class file, even though the IDE can find it and lets me use it. Is there an easy way to add it?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create Application Class

```
class AppClass : Application()
{
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this
    }
    companion object {
        var context: Context? = null
            internal set
    }
}
```

> 2. Declare application class in Manifest. under application tag.

```
 <application
        android:name=“.AppClass"
```

> 3. Create class to read file from raw folder

```
class ReadFile {
    fun ReadXmlFile(): List<String>
    {
        val dataList = ArrayList<String>()
        var factory: XmlPullParserFactory? = null
        var data = ""
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
            val xpp = factory!!.newPullParser()
            val open = App.context!!.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.datafile)
            xpp.setInput(open, "UTF_8")

            var eventType = xpp.eventType
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                    if (xpp.name.equals("Data", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        xpp.next()
                        data = xpp.text
                        dataList.add(data)

                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                }

                eventType = xpp.next() // move to next element
            }
        } catch (e: XmlPullParserException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return dataList;
    }

}
```

> 4. Sample datafile.xml  in raw folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main>
    <item>
        <Data>Data 1.</Data>
    </item>

    <item>
        <Data>Data 2.</Data>
    </item>
</main>
```

> 5. Read file in activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       val  dataList = ReadFile().ReadXmlFile()
        Log.d("TAG", dataList.toString());
    }
}
```